# Action in Gmail add on trigger to display a particular message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

Is it possible to trigger a specific email to load from an action inside a Gmail add on. i.e. build an add-on where a click of a button loads a specific thread id in the same window (as opposed to open a new window or tab) to display that message.

Comment: I don't think there is. All UI related goes through [Cards](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/cards). And these cards can only contain [widgets](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/widgets). And from the looks of it, I don't think you can display a full thread in it.

Comment: Just to clarify I want the action/trigger to happen inside the add-on but the email message to load in the usual place (not in the add-on). as an example in Gmail the current view is the inbox, through an action in the add-on I would like to open a particular message in place of the inbox.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So basically redirect the current tab to a specific thread on button click. Can you add the code that enables you to display that message on another tab?

Comment: Yes, this is how it is currently done. It works ok but ideally, it would load on the same page. The other downside to loading in a new tab/window is the Gmail add-on is not open in the new tab.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do it. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/open-as